# Prevent direct route access from a lazy-loaded module

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

From one of my modules (`MasterModule`), I load the `MasterComponent` and its child routes. One of these child routes lazy loads my `EquipmentSLModule` :

**master-routing.module.ts** :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'master', redirectTo: '/master/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'master',
    component: MasterComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
      },

      ...  // Other routes

      {
        path: 'SL',
        loadChildren: './../equipment/equipment-SL.module#EquipmentSLModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

From this sub-module, I add child routes :

**equipment-SL-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'toto',
    component: EquipmentComponent,
  },
];
```

I can then access my route `master/SL/toto` successfully, but I can also directly go to `/toto` from the URL and it works as well. 
Is there a way to prevent the access to `/toto` only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent the access to `/toto` for no reason just remove it from your routing configuration, or use `CanActivate` if you want to make some conditions.

```
//equipment-SL-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: EquipmentComponent,
  },
];
```

Comment: I cannot remove it, as it is defining the routing from the `equipment-SL-routing.module.ts` because I need the `master/SL/toto` route from the lazy-load. No other option than `CanActivate` ?

Comment: It wont change the issue, I will be able to reach `'/master/SL'` (which is what I want), but I will also be able to manually go to `' '` which is not good

Comment: no it's impossible only if you use `forRoot` instead of `forChild` in ` `equipment-SL-routing.module.ts` or you add `component: EquipmentComponent` somewhere in `master-routing.module.ts`, can you show all your routing configurations

Answer (score -1):

Just delete the import of EquipmentModule from your AppModule, then use loadChildren